# Set baseline programmatically in ProjectServer

Tags: project-server, ms-project-server-2010

How I can set the baseline programmatic-ally in Microsoft project server?
Are there any blogs about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure in what context you are working.
If you are in VSTO, try this:  [Application.BaselineSave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office.vbapj.chm610.aspx)

As far as I know PSI does not offer a method to set a baseline [What PSI does and does not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee767706%28v=office.15%29.aspx)